# Cannot import name '_centered' from 'scipy.signal.signaltools'

Tags: python, scipy

Unable to import functions from scipy module.

Gives error :

```
from scipy.signal.signaltools import _centered
Cannot import name '_centered' from 'scipy.signal.signaltools'

scipy.__version__
1.8.0
```

Comment: You can try to update the package using pip or conda. I recently had another package break my scipy with, I think but am not entirely sure, the same error message. Updating the package worked for me

Comment: use scipy lower versions like 1.7.3 which will work.

Comment: That leading underscore in the name `_centered` tells you that it is a private function.  You cannot rely on private functions persisting between versions of SciPy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you need to use that specific version of statsmodels 0.12.x with scipy 1.8.0 I have the following *hack*.
Basically it just re-publishes the existing (but private) _centered function as a public attribute to the module already imported in RAM.

It is a workaround, and if you can simply upgrade your dependencies to the latest versions. Only use this if you are forced to use those specific versions.

```
import  scipy.signal.signaltools

def _centered(arr, newsize):
    # Return the center newsize portion of the array.
    newsize = np.asarray(newsize)
    currsize = np.array(arr.shape)
    startind = (currsize - newsize) // 2
    endind = startind + newsize
    myslice = [slice(startind[k], endind[k]) for k in range(len(endind))]
    return arr[tuple(myslice)]

scipy.signal.signaltools._centered = _centered
```

Answer (score 21):

I encountered the same problem while using `statsmodels~=0.12.x`. Increasing the [statsmodels](https://pypi.org/project/statsmodels/#history) package to version `0.13.2`, this import issue is resolved.

UPDATE with more notes:

- before:

  - installation of fixed version of `statsmodels==0.12.2` which is dependent on `scipy`
  - there was newly [released](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/#history) `scipy==1.8.0` -  2022-02-05

    - when installing it, got this problem:

```sh
    from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.py", line 12, in <module>
    from statsmodels.tsa.filters.filtertools import convolution_filter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/filters/filtertools.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scipy.signal.signaltools import _centered as trim_centered
ImportError: cannot import name '_centered' from 'scipy.signal.signaltools' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.py)
```

- after:

  - when bumping up `statsmodels` to the latest version available `0.13.2` release 2022-02-08, it works
- If you are not using `statsmodels` but other package which is dependent on `scipy`, have a look if there is newer version available (after the release of `scipy` to v.`1.8.0`)

Answer (score 11):

As it was mentioned by [AndrejHan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18231148/andrejhan) and [ThomasCokelaer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3690711/thomas-cokelaer), you need to upgrade to `statsmodels-0.13.2` with:

```
$ pip install statsmodels --upgrade
```

or

```
$ python3 -m pip install statsmodels --upgrade
```

Your error should disappear

Answer (score 2):

With scipy 1.8.0, the deprecated form

`from scipy.signal.signaltools import _centered`

should become

`from scipy.signal._signaltools import _centered`

Note the underscore in front of signaltools