# I am using Orange3 and loading Timeseries addon. The add-on does NOT show and on the console I have an error

Tags: scipy, orange

I am using Orange3 version 3.32 and Timeseries 0.3.12 .
When I add the add-on Timeseries, the add-on is NOT visible and I receive the message:
ImportError: cannot import name '_centered' from 'scipy.signal.signaltools' (/home/capurso/anaconda3/envs/orange3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.py)

I am using
statsmodels-0.12.2  and scipy-1.8.1

Consulting the following link
[Cannot import name '_centered' from 'scipy.signal.signaltools'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71106940/cannot-import-name-centered-from-scipy-signal-signaltools)

I changed in

/home/capurso/anaconda3/envs/orange3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/filters/filtertools.py

the text

from scipy.signal.signaltools import _centered

that should become

from scipy.signal._signaltools import _centered

Note the underscore in front of signaltools

I have solved the problem. Have you better solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

This add-on used old versions of scipy and stats, so things began falling apart. Your fix would solve some problems, but not all.

An even better solution is to download the newest version of the add-on, which was released today. :) It also contains lots of other improvements in several widgets.